# Spring Cloud version Hoxton.SR5 is giving XML format as HTTP response by default

Tags: json, xml, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

When I am using `<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR5</spring-cloud.version>` in my Spring Boot application it is returning me an XML format in the HTTP response by default:

```xml
<List>
    <item>
        <productId>1</productId>
        <productName>Samsung LED TV</productName
        <quantity>100</quantity
        <itemType>TV</itemType>
        <itemGroup>Entertainement</itemGroup>
    </item>
</List>
```

And When I am using `<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>`, it is returning JSON Format:

```json
[
    {
        "productId": 1,
        "productName": "Samsung LED TV",
        "quantity": 100,
        "itemType": "TV",
        "itemGroup": "Entertainement"
    }
]
```

What are the changes made in `Hoxton.SR5` that it is returning XML format by default and how can I make sure that I get JSON format while using `Hoxton.SR5`?.

Comment: yeah something changed inbetween Hoxton.SR4 vs Hoxton.SR5, a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929410/hoxton-sr6-with-spring-boot-2-3-0-cause-weird-content-type-issue

Comment: Also, i see that if no Accept headers are specified, Spring Boot makes it Accept: [application/xml, text/xml, application/json, application/*+xml, application/*+json], giving priority to application/xml. One potential solution is to specify the Accept headers manually Accept: [application/json]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by eureka-client upgrade which brought jackson-dataformat-xml to the classpath.